# Append data.frame objects from an environment to corresponding data.frame objects in GlobalEnv (or another env) in R

Tags: r, dataframe, append, environment

I have several existing `data.frame` objects that need to be updated from the Internet. However, as the updates have the same names as the mentioned existing objects, I put the updates in a separate environment also as `data.frame` objects.

Then, the idea is to append the updates to the existing `data.frame` objects. But I don't see how I can do that iteratively (i.e., in a loop?) with `rbind` from one environment to `GlobalEnv` (or another environment, for that matter).

Also, I did not put them here, but there will be several other `data.frame` objects (with other names) that will in the `GlobalEnv` (or the environment where they will be loaded).

Here below is a piece of code that should be reproducible (with comments and links to the sources):

````
library(quantmod)

# Load ticker data from 2020-01-01 till 2021-02-02
tickers <- c("NKLA", "MPNGF", "RMO", "JD", "MSFT")
getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = globalenv(), 
                 from = "2020-01-01", to = "2021-02-02")

# Close all Internet connections as a precaution
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758758/2950721
closeAllConnections()

# Find xts objects
xtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts))))

# Convert xts to data.frame
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/69246047/2950721
for (i in seq_along(xtsObjects)) {
  assign(xtsObjects[i], fortify.zoo(get(xtsObjects[i])))
}


# Redo the previous process but in separate environment for updated
# values of the same tickers (comments and sources are not repeated)
symbolUpdates.env <- new.env()

getSymbols.yahoo(tickers, auto.assign = TRUE, env = symbolUpdates.env,
                 from = "2021-02-03")

closeAllConnections()

symbolUpdatesXtsObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(symbolUpdates.env, 
                                                     is.xts))))

for (i in seq_along(symbolUpdatesXtsObjects)) {
  assign(envir = symbolUpdates.env, symbolUpdatesXtsObjects[i], 
         fortify.zoo(get(symbolUpdatesXtsObjects[i], 
                         envir = symbolUpdates.env)))
}

# Find ```data.frame``` objects both in ```GlobalEnv``` and 
# ```symbolUpdates.env```
globalEnvDataframeObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, 
                                                        is.data.frame))))
symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects <- names(which(unlist(eapply(symbolUpdates.env, 
                                                           is.data.frame))))


# This rbind definitely does not work!!!
for (i in seq_along(globalEnvDataframeObjects)) {
  rbind(envir = .GlobalEnv, globalEnvDataframeObjects[i], envir =
  symbolUpdates.env, symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects[i])
}
````

My questions:

- With preferably no additional packages than the basic `R` ones, what piece of code can iteratively append `symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects` to the corresponding `globalEnvDataframeObjects`?
- Would the code be the same should `globalEnvDataframeObjects` be in another environment (i.e., not `.GlobalEnv`, but a "sub-environment" like `symbolUpdates.env`)?

  - If not, what would change?
- Is there a better/wiser approach than the one I'm trying to use?

Thanks in advance.

---

Systems used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Comment: where do you want to update the objects rbinded

Comment: The `symbolUpdatesDataObjects` columns have duplicated Index column.  So, it is giving 8 columns while the interObj is giving 7 columns for each data.  Therefore we need to remove the extra column.  I used `[-1]`

Comment: Also, I find the column names in `symbolUpdatesDateaObjects` are kind of assigned differently.  You can check `sapply(mget(symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects, envir = symbolUpdates.env), names)`

Comment: Can you please correct those errors and the code below should work then

Comment: Thanks for your comments akrun. Could you kindly tell me where to put the ```[-1]```?

Comment: Any ideas as to why in ```symbolUpdates.env``` an additional ```Index``` column appears? I rechecked the whole code, made several iterations and all of them put an additional ```Index``` column if it is in another environment than ```.GlobalEnv```.

Comment: Ok, I got the answer: the ```fortify.zoo(get(symbolUpdatesXtsObjects[i])``` at the end of the code should have read ```fortify.zoo(get(symbolUpdatesXtsObjects[i], envir = symbolUpdates.env)```. The code above now works for me meaning no additional ```Index``` column. :-)

Comment: @pdeli your code is not R like, usng assign in the manner you have constantly is considered bad R (please see here)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559390/why-is-using-assign-bad. Please see my solution below.

Comment: @hello_friend, thanks for your comment. And you are probably right. However, the piece of code I need will have to be integrated into a much bigger one and in order to use your solutions it would need a complete re-write. Which I definitely will have to do sometimes in the future. In the meantime, kindly check out my comment to your post.

Answer (score 1):

We may need `intersect` here

```
interObj <- intersect(globalEnvDataframeObjects, symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects)
interObj <- interObj[match(interObj, symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects)]
nrow(get(interObj[1]))
[1] 273
for (i in seq_along(interObj)) {
  assign(interObj[i], rbind(get(interObj[i], envir = .GlobalEnv), 
    get(symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects[i], envir = symbolUpdates.env)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: akrun, would you mind pointing to the repository where ```intersect``` is, because I keep on getting warnings that ```package ‘Intersect’ is not available for this version of R```. I of course enabled all the repositories with ```setRepositories()``` and checked with ```available.packages()```.

Comment: @pdeli `intersect` is a `base R` function.  It is all lowercaps

Comment: Oups. My bad. Sorry akrun. Your code works until ```nrow(get(interObj[1]))```. However when I run the ```for``` loop, I get the following message: ```Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names```. Could it be because ```interObj``` after the ```match``` shows a different order in the objects (i.e, before: ```[1] "NKLA"  "MPNGF" "MSFT"  "JD"    "RMO"```, after: ```[1] "MPNGF" "RMO"   "JD"    "MSFT"  "NKLA"```)?

Comment: I found the solution. I used the ```sort``` command so that both ```symbolUpdatesDataframeObjects``` and ```interObj``` have the same order. And now it seems to work every time.

Comment: @pdeli The `match` should also work.  Maybe it was because there was some elements that more in interObj and that results in `NA`

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to store the data.frames in multiple environments use the following:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: necessary_packages => vector
necessary_packages <- c("quantmod")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => vector
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:
if(length(new_packages) > 0){
  install.packages(
    new_packages, 
    dependencies = TRUE
  )
}

# Initialise the packages in the session: list of boolean => stdout (console)
lapply(
  necessary_packages, 
  require, 
  character.only = TRUE
)

# Load ticker data from 2020-01-01 till 2021-02-02
tickers <- c(
  "NKLA", 
  "MPNGF", 
  "RMO", 
  "JD", 
  "MSFT"
)

# Create a new environment: environment => symbolUpdates.env
symbolUpdates.env <- new.env()

# Create a vector of from dates: from_dates => Date Vector
from_dates <- as.Date(
  c(
    "2020-01-01", 
    "2020-02-03"
  )
)

# Create a vector of to dates:
to_dates <- as.Date(
  c(
    "2021-02-02", 
    format(
      Sys.Date(),
      "%Y-%m-%d"
    )
  )
)

# Create a vetor environments: env_vec => vector of environments
env_vec <- c(
  .GlobalEnv, 
  symbolUpdates.env
)

# Function to retreive ticker as a data.frame: 
# retrieve_ticker_df => function()
retrieve_ticker_df <- function(ticker_vec, from_date, to_date){
  
  # Create a list of size length(tickers):
  # df_list => empty list
  df_list <- vector(
    "list", 
    length(ticker_vec)
  )
  
  # Store each ticker's response as a data.frame in the list:
  # df_list => list of data.frames
  df_list <- setNames(
    lapply(
      seq_along(ticker_vec),
      function(i){
        # Retrieve the data.frame: tmp => data.frame
        tmp <- getSymbols.yahoo(
          ticker_vec[i],
          auto.assign = FALSE, 
          from = from_date,
          to = to_date,
          return.class = 'data.frame',
        )
        
        # Close all Internet connections as a precaution
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758758/2950721
        closeAllConnections()
        
        # Create a data.frame and revert index to sequential
        # integers: data.frame => env
        data.frame(
          cbind(
            date = as.Date(
              row.names(
                tmp
              )
            ),
            tmp
          ),
          row.names = NULL
        )
      }
    ),
    ticker_vec
  )
  # Explicitly define returned object: list of data.frames => env
  return(df_list)
}

# Store all the data.frames in a list of data.frames, 
# store each list of data.frames in a list: 
# ticker_df_list_list => list of list of data.frames
ticker_df_list_list <- lapply(
  seq_along(env_vec),
  function(i){
    retrieve_ticker_df(
      tickers, 
      from_dates[i], 
      to_dates[i]
    )
  }
)

# Push each of the lists to the appropriate environment: 
# data.frames => env
lapply(
  seq_along(ticker_df_list_list),
  function(i){
    list2env(
      ticker_df_list_list[[i]],
      envir = env_vec[[i]]
    )
  }
)

# Initialise an empty list to create some memory
# bound_df_list => empty list
bound_df_list <- vector(
  "list", 
  length(tickers)
)

# Allocate some memory by initialising an
# empty list: ir_list => list
ir_list <- vector(
  "list",
  length(env_vec) * length(tickers)
)

# Unlist the env_vec, and retrieve the ticker
# data.frames: ir_list => list of data.frames
ir_list <- unlist(
  lapply(
    env_vec,
    function(x){
      mget(
        tickers, 
        envir = x
      )
    }
  ),
  recursive = FALSE
)

# Split-apply-combine based on the 
# data.frame names: bound_df_list => list of data.frames
bound_df_list <- lapply(
  split(
    ir_list,
    names(ir_list)
  ),
  function(x){
    do.call(
      rbind, 
      x
    )
  }
)

# Clear up the intermediate objects:
rm(ticker_df_list_list, ir_list, env_vec); gc()
```

If it is not mandatory to use multiple environments:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: necessary_packages => vector
necessary_packages <- c("quantmod")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => vector
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:
if(length(new_packages) > 0){
  install.packages(
    new_packages, 
    dependencies = TRUE
  )
}

# Initialise the packages in the session: list of boolean => stdout (console)
lapply(
  necessary_packages, 
  require, 
  character.only = TRUE
)

# Load ticker data from 2020-01-01 till 2021-02-02
tickers <- c(
  "NKLA", 
  "MPNGF", 
  "RMO", 
  "JD", 
  "MSFT"
)

# Create a new environment: environment => symbolUpdates.env
symbolUpdates.env <- new.env()

# Create a vector of from dates: from_dates => Date Vector
from_dates <- as.Date(
  c(
    "2020-01-01", 
    "2020-02-03"
  )
)

# Create a vector of to dates:
to_dates <- as.Date(
  c(
    "2021-02-02", 
    format(
      Sys.Date(),
      "%Y-%m-%d"
    )
  )
)

# Function to retreive ticker as a data.frame: 
# retrieve_ticker_df => function()
retrieve_ticker_df <- function(ticker_vec, from_date, to_date){

  # Create a list of size length(tickers):
  # df_list => empty list
  df_list <- vector(
    "list", 
    length(ticker_vec)
  )
  
  # Store each ticker's response as a data.frame in the list:
  # df_list => list of data.frames
  df_list <- setNames(
    lapply(
      seq_along(ticker_vec),
      function(i){
        # Retrieve the data.frame: tmp => data.frame
        tmp <- getSymbols.yahoo(
          ticker_vec[i],
          auto.assign = FALSE, 
          from = from_date,
          to = to_date,
          return.class = 'data.frame',
        )
        
        # Close all Internet connections as a precaution
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758758/2950721
        closeAllConnections()
        
        # Create a data.frame and revert index to sequential
        # integers: data.frame => env
        data.frame(
          cbind(
            date = as.Date(
              row.names(
                tmp
              )
            ),
            tmp
          ),
          row.names = NULL
        )
      }
    ),
    ticker_vec
  )
  # Explicitly define returned object: list of data.frames => env
  return(df_list)
}

# Store all the data.frames in a list of data.frames, 
# store each list of data.frames in a list: 
# ticker_df_list_list => list of list of data.frames
ticker_df_list_list <- lapply(
  seq_along(from_dates),
  function(i){
    retrieve_ticker_df(
      tickers, 
      from_dates[i], 
      to_dates[i]
    )
  }
)

# Initialise an empty list to create some memory:
# ir_list => empty list
ir_list <- vector(
  "list",
  length(tickers) * length(from_dates)
)

# Populate the list with each of the named data.frames: 
# ir_list => list of data.frames
ir_list <- unlist(
  ticker_df_list_list, 
  recursive = FALSE
)

# Initialise an empty list to create some memory
# bound_df_list => empty list
bound_df_list <- vector(
  "list", 
  length(tickers)
)

# Split-apply-combine: bound_df_list => list of data.frames
bound_df_list <- lapply(
  split(
    ir_list,
    names(ir_list)
  ),
  function(x){
    do.call(
      rbind, 
      x
    )
  }
)

# Clear up the intermediate objects:
rm(ticker_df_list_list, ir_list); gc()
```

Comment: Thanks @hello_friend. Both codes you posted work fine. However, the code where the solution will go loads from local storage all the tickers. Then, the codes checks those that are not up-to-date and downloads the delta between their last date and today (lets call them delta-tickers). Then I need to append the delta-tickers to the not up-to-date tickers. That is why my question is: "how to append the delta between the last date of the not up-to-date tickers and today to the not up-to-date tickers?".

Comment: @pdeli cool, then you only need to update the from and to dates vectors to be dynamic and then you can get a delta export.

Comment: Thank you @hello_friend. Will try what you suggested and come back to you.